# Textbox inside Modal Popup becomes empty on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

Textbox inside modal popup becomes empty on button click. I am getting empty string on code behind. Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Sure, if you show the code for the event.

Comment: this is unclear.please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

which modal is that? 
if this is an fancyBox modal u should use this one the configuration of the fancybox:
parent: "form:first"